# Want to calculate difference record count in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, record, subtraction

I am trying to determine the difference between record counts, where I only have two different record types. I want to show the record count for each record type and group by date:

```
select 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), aa.RUN_DATE, 1) AS 'RUN_Date',
    case 
       when aa.SOURCE = 2 
          then 'RD' 
          else 'JD' 
    end as 'Source',
    COUNT(*) as 'Item_Count'
from 
    clientdb.inventory aa with(nolock)
inner join 
    clientdb.record_type bb with(nolock) on aa.REC_TYPE = bb.OBJECT_ID
where
    aa.RUN_DATE > '2016-04-15'
    and aa.CLIENT_NUMBER = 65432
group by
    case 
       when aa.SOURCE = 2 
          then 'RD' 
          else 'JD' 
    end, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), aa.RUN_DATE, 1) 
order by
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), aa.RUN_DATE, 1) desc,
    case 
       when aa.SOURCE = 2 
          then 'RD' 
          else 'JD' 
    end
```

I would like the results to appear in some way similar to this:

[image: results]

Using SQL Server 2008 database. Can someone help?

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a situation where you could use [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410).

This is assuming the you can summarize your data to a structure similar to what I have created below...

```
RUN_Date   JD          RD          Difference
---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2016-04-29 163         263         100
2016-04-28 178         271         93
2016-04-27 95          271         176
```

For the purposes of this example the following script will create that table...

```
create table BaseSummary
(
    RUN_Date date,
    JD int,
    RD int,
    Difference int
)

insert into BaseSummary values ('04/29/2016', 163, 263, 100)
insert into BaseSummary values ('04/28/2016', 178, 271, 93)
insert into BaseSummary values ('04/27/2016', 95, 271, 176)
```

Here is the SQL statement using UNPIVOT to get what you are looking for...

```
select RUN_Date, left(Source, 16) as Source, Item_Count
from 
(
    select RUN_Date, JD, RD, Difference
    from BaseSummary
) p
UNPIVOT
(
    Item_Count for Source in 
        (JD, RD, Difference)
) as unpvt
order by RUN_Date desc
```

Which yields this...

```
RUN_Date   Source           Item_Count
---------- ---------------- -----------
2016-04-29 JD               163
2016-04-29 RD               263
2016-04-29 Difference       100
2016-04-28 JD               178
2016-04-28 RD               271
2016-04-28 Difference       93
2016-04-27 JD               95
2016-04-27 RD               271
2016-04-27 Difference       176
```

So you could summarize your data an insert it to a table or even a temp table and replace "BaseSummary" with your table. I have not tested this, but I don't see any reason why you couldn't just replace the query aliased as "p" with your summarizing query.

Hope this helps,

Noel